# how to emit two signals in pyqt5

Tags: python, interface, pyqt5

below is a groubox with 3 radio and one push button

so far connecting one widget to slot is fairly easy 
`self.versuch_2_radio.toggled.connect(self.printstuff())`

but how can i emit 2 signals to one slot ?

in pseudocode I want to execute `self.versuch_2_radio.toggled() and self.select_button.clicked() print('something')`

or do I need to create two slots ?

```
        self.groupbox = qtw.QGroupBox(self)
        # groupbox.setAlignment(qtc.Qt.AlignHCenter)

        vlayout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        vlayout.setAlignment(qtc.Qt.AlignHCenter)

        versuch_1_radio = qtw.QRadioButton("toggle1")
        vlayout.addWidget(versuch_1_radio)
        self.versuch_2_radio = qtw.QRadioButton("toggle2")
        vlayout.addWidget(self.versuch_2_radio)
        versuch_3_radio = qtw.QRadioButton("toggle3")
        vlayout.addWidget(versuch_3_radio)
        self.select_button = qtw.QPushButton('select')
        vlayout.addWidget(self.select_button)

        self.groupbox.setLayout(vlayout)

        # hauptlayout
        haupt_layout = qtw.QFormLayout()
        haupt_layout.addRow(benutzer_label)
        haupt_layout.addRow(ueberschrift_label)
        haupt_layout.setVerticalSpacing(40)
        haupt_layout.addRow(self.groupbox)

        self.setLayout(haupt_layout)

  def printstuff(self):
        print("connected")
```

Comment: Explain yourself better, do you want "printstuff" to be called when the status of the QRadioButton changes **or** the QPushButton is pressed, OR when the QPushButton is pressed **and** the status of the QRadioButton is pressed?

Comment: when the QPushButton is pressed and the status of the QRadioButton is pressed, for example versuch_3_radio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is only to detect the clicked QPushButton and to verify the status of the QRadioButton in the slot:

```
self.select_button.clicked.connect(self.printstuff)
```

```
def printstuff(self):
    if self.versuch_2_radio.isChecked():
        print("connected")
```

Comment: I get a `TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable`, `self.select_button.clicked(self.printstuff)`